# Buggy jQuery <div> slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I'm trying to build a div slider with HTML, CSS and jQuery (which I don't have good knowledge yet).

The problem is that when I can't display a third div, and when I do (with some changes in the code) it cant go to the previous slide.

Could you help me with the code please. And sorry for some messy and strange syntax, I'm still not very good at it.

jQuery code for the slider:

```
$(function () {
    $('a.scroll').on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var $anchor = $(this),
        $section = $anchor.attr('data-section');

        if ($section === '4' || $section === '2' || $section === '3') {
          $('#wrap .wrap-inner').addClass('goto-' + $section);
        } else {
          $('#wrap .wrap-inner').removeClass('goto-2 goto-3');
        }
    });
});
```

The HTML and CSS itself are present on the fiddle below, but is an example of the second :

```
<div class="section" id="section2">
    <div class="arrowDiv"><a class="scroll" href="#section1" data-section="1"><img class="white"src="imgs/go_back.png" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="form formTitle">
         <h1 class="alpha">Second</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="arrowDiv"><a class="scroll" href="#section3" data-section="3"><img class="white"src="imgs/go_next.png" /></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's my fiddle: http://bit.ly/1cUCUF6

Answers I'm looking for: how to make it display more than 2 divs and how to make the back and next arrows work on every slide.

Comment: Hi, I'd suggest showing parts of the code into your question.

Comment: Ok, let me edit then.